# percona pt-table sync message Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, percona

I am using pt-table sync on my environment ,I am using below command for sync

/percona-toolkit/2.2.7/bin/pt-table-sync --execute --sync-to-master --no-unique-checks --no-check-child-tables --no-foreign-key-checks  --databases=dbname h=localhost  -uroot  -ppwd  -P 3306

miss matched data synced but get below message,

Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause [for Statement "SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`macaddress`)) FROM `dbname`.`tablename01` ORDER BY `macaddress`"] at line 4060 while doing whirl.newPluginsLog on localhost

I want to confirm that these occur due to some miss configuration in MySQL server or some thing wrong in my tables or I missed out some switch with pt-table-sync.

or it is a bug in pt-table-sync ?

Comment: this happens if you have the `only_full_group_by` mode enabled.

Comment: Hi Barmar,  thanks for reply , is there any switch available in pt-table-sync for disable it .

Comment: No idea, I don't know anything about Percona. This is a MySQL setting, normally this option is off.

Comment: ok thanks , I got it , I have to disable it before running percona.  thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Barmar , it clear my doubts and help me to solve this issue.
actually in my.cnf sql_mode  contains ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ,that why I am facing issue with percona pt-table-sync.

I simple disable it from both master and slave server by using set global sql_mode and remove this variable "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" , and run pt-table-sync ,it start working .

thanks for Barmar who shows me right direction.